# Are consonant skips allowed below and above the notes of resolution of a suspension in 5th species counterpoint?

Tags: counterpoint

In my textbook and most places I could find online it shows consonant skips as a way to decorate suspensions in 5th species counterpoint. The consonant skip always happens below the suspended note. Can a skip like this be used above as well?

Comment: Just curious, what textbook are you working from?